# If clause not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to enter an if only if the value of a jquery object is empty and the dom element isn't a label or span. So i have

```
$('.container').children().each(function (index, item2){
    if ($(item2).val()=== '' && (item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'label' || item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'span')){
        //do stuff here
        console.log("tag: "+item2.tagName.toLowerCase());
    }
});
```

but in the console I get

```
tag: label
```

meaning that it's not working correctly. Am I missing something there?

Comment: It should be `$(item2).val() !== ''`.

Comment: Corrected it I want to enter the if when value is empty sorry to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is:

```
$('.container').children().each(function (index, item2){
   if ($(item2).val()=== '' && (item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'label' || item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'span')){           
     console.log("tag: "+item2.tagName.toLowerCase());
   }
});
```

Here you write your condition :- `$(item2).val() === '' && (item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'label' || item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'span')`

First of all if you want to allow non-empty value element use `!==` instead of using `===` (as @Rory McCrossan suggest).

Now we talk about your second condition i.e. - `(item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'label' || item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'span')`

means here you allow if element is `LABEL` OR `SPAN`.

So, your condition goes into following four ways -

```
(false || true ) ====>  true  // Element is label

(true || false ) ====>  true // Element is span

(true || true ) ====>  true // Element is not a span and not a label

(false || false ) ====>  false // Element is a span and also an label [this condition never satisfied]
```

I think, here you are wrong. You should use following condition (if you don't allow both type of element)-

`$(item2).val() === '' && (item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'label' && item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'span')`

In short you must use `&&/AND` instead of using `||/OR`.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is wrong, try below:

```
$('.container').children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '' && !$(this).is('span') && !$(this).is('label')) {
        console.log("tag: "+item2.tagName.toLowerCase());
    }
});
```

But `span` and `label` doesn't has `value` attribute, if you mean to check whether the element has no children (including text nodes), there is **[:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** selector.

```
$('.container').children().each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':empty, span, label')) {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

**[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xyw3c/)**.

Comment: You can also combine the label/span test to `!$(this).is( 'span, label' )`

Comment: issue with second one is that an input, even with value, is always empty

Comment: I like the is method didn't know it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enter the condition if the value **isn't empty** you need to use `!==` instead of `===`.

```
if ($(item2).val() !== '' && (item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'label' || item2.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'span')) {
    // your code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite that to

```
$('.container').children().each(function (index, item2){
    if ( item2.value ) {

    }
});
```

A span or a label has no value, so those will fail the condition anyway

Comment: @A.Wolff - yeah, an empty string is falsy, so checking for length shouldn't really be neccessary.

Comment: this is the most concise answer here and the less upvoted (not counting me in). Strange SO sometimes...